# Десериализация вложенного объекта из JSON

Tags: java, jackson

У меня есть вот такой объект:

```
public final class ValueObject {
    String ceId;
    Map<String, Object> params;
}
```

После сериализации я получаю такую строку:

```
{
  "ceId":"{E99D1098-65B7-4A09-BE03-9FD9E0F967E0}",
  "params":{
    "Barcode":null,
    "ContractorLink":{
      "ceId":"{C9903B58-AAB1-46C5-9462-AE148C4B6DA8}",
      "params":{
        "ClassDescription":"UPUDContractorFolder",
        "OSIdentity":"DEFAULT",
        "Id":"{C9903B58-AAB1-46C5-9462-AE148C4B6DA8}"
      }
    },
    "RegistryStatus":"0000",
    "UPUDRegisterContractNumber":null,
    "ParentObjectID":null
  }
}
```

Но когда я десериализую её обратно (используя Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean):

```
voTemp = jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.readValue(pVo, ValueObject.class);
```

я получаю LinkedHashMap вместо моего класса в *ContractorLink*.
Можно ли как-то повлиять на такое поведение?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать собственный десериализатор, зарегистрировать его в контексте и настлаждаться)
Вот, [сюда можно посмотреть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
Есть еще неплохая реализация работы с JSON - [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). И статья на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/)

Comment: Свой десериалайзер это не очень идея (для сложного объекта), так проще и вовсе от jackson оказаться.

Answer (score 1):

В своё время быстро сделать что-то вразумительное и красивое с такой же проблемой у меня не получилось. И я перешел с jackson на [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/). Он уже из коробки может сохранять классы при сереализации-десереализации(прям в JSON добавляет поле class). Единственная проблема у меня возникла из-за не *ACSII* символов, пришлось свой трансформатор добавлять:

```
new JSONSerializer().transform( new AbstractTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transform(Object object) {

            String value = object.toString();
            int len = value.length();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("\"");
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                char c = value.charAt( i );
                if (c == '"') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\u0022" );
                } else if (c == '&') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\u0026" );
                } else if (c == '\'') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\u0027" );
                } else if (c == '\\') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\\\" );
                } else if (c == '\b') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\b" );
                } else if (c == '\f') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\f" );
                } else if (c == '\n') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\n" );
                } else if (c == '\r') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\r" );
                } else if (c == '\t') {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\t" );
                } else if (c > 127) {
                    stringBuilder.append( "\\u" );
                    int n = c;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                        int digit = (n & 0xf000) >> 12;
                        stringBuilder.append( String.valueOf( JSONSerializer.HEX[digit] ) );
                        n <<= 4;
                    }
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append( c );
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.append( "\"" );
            getContext().write( stringBuilder.toString() );
        }
    }, String.class );
```